# python-social-auth : Supporting subdomains in redirect uri for facebook in Django

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-social-auth

I have facebook login working for my domain: example.com(just for example). 
In the facebook developer settings I have set redirect uri as : http://example.com/complete/facebook/

and this works fine.

I want to support the same facebook login for all the subdomains of example.com; for eg: 2.example.com, abc.example.com and so on.

One way is to manually put these above URLs as the redirect uris in facebook, but I do not want this.

After 2 days of searching & experimenting I figured out this could be a solution:

1. suppose my website's user is on 2.example.com, user clicks on facebook login.
2. before going to facebook, I redirect the user on example.com
3. the signup request is send to facebook with redirect uri now as: http://example.com:8000/complete/facebook/ instead of http://2.example.com:8000/complete/facebook/
4. for preserving my site_id which is 2 in the above case, I pass an extra argument attached with the request sent to facebook.
5. After I receive the user detail's response from facebook, I also get the site_id parameter back to me which was passed in step 4.
6. After which I use the site_id and redirect the user to http://2.example.com:8000/.

I want to know if this is achievable in Django using python-social-auth and how ? Also, if there is any other efficient way of solving this problem.

Comment: With "One way is to manually put these above URLs as the redirect uris in facebook, but I do not want this." you mean you don't want to set the redirect URI as parameter when calling the FB login? Why not? You could then use Django's `request.build_absolute_uri()`. Quite clean, understandable to other developers, without unnecessary redirects.

Comment: I do not want to put these urls manually because my website generates these sub-domains dynamically. I want the example.com as my base domain to work for all its sub-domains

Comment: `request.build_absolute_uri()` would simply use the subdomain that is currently used for that user and request. It would be fine to stick to that during the social auth process? With "manually" do you mean "hard coded"? See implementation: https://github.com/django/django/blob/ecb59cc6579402b68ddfd4499bf30edacf5963be/django/http/request.py#L163

Comment: Thanx, but i solved this the other way.
using this :
http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/use_cases.html#pass-custom-get-post-parameters-and-retrieve-them-on-authentication

i can now pass my site id as extra parameter,

and by manually I didnt meant hard coded, I meant putting domain one by one.